# gtext: specify number of lines

Tags: r, gwidgets

I'm using gWidgets GUI fronted package in R. I can specify height of `gtext()` in pixel, but... how can I specify the height of gtext in number of lines of text (like in textarea in html ...)?

In particular, I need only one line text input field. Like `<input type="text">` in html, but `gtext()` works more like `<textarea>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @jverzani's comment - the solution is to use `gedit` for single line entry, like:

```
xyear <- gedit("1980", height = 1, horizontal = F)
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution (little tricky) , you can use **font** metrics to set it.

```
library(gWidgets)
options(guiToolkit="RGtk2") 
w <- gwindow("brush example", visible=FALSE)

font.height <- 6   ## I don't know to get x-large metrics, so I fix it here
font.width  <- 50
obj <- gtext(container=w,height=5*font.height, width=5*font.width,
             font.attr=c(
  style="monospace", 
  color="blue", 
  size="x-large"))
add(obj,"mono blue large")
visible(w) <-  TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks, however: 1) quite dirty, isn't it? 2) font.heght 6 pixels only??? For x-large? 3) the `add` command seems wrong - normally it uses the group/window as first argument and the object as second...

Comment: Yes it is quite dirty! The main Idea is to get Height from font metrics. The command add is correct. Dis you test this dirty code? I upvoted your question . I am waiting for a clean solution.

Comment: That is basically what can be done as the size in Gtk is given in pixels. However, what you probably want here is `gedit` for single line entry.

Comment: @jverzani thanks !Now I a am sure, I get my clean solution :)

Comment: @JVERzani - thanks for great answer! - please post this as answer, I will upvote and accept!